# Problems with WP 6.1.1 and the get_user_meta() function

Tags: customization, user-meta

On upgrading from **v6.0.3** **to v6.1.1**, the function **get_user_meta()** (used in my theme) is **not** working correctly!

In the following code **v6.1.1** returns **$guid** as an empty value, however when I revert back to **v6.0.3** all works as expected and **$guid** is correct (obviously for the same **$memberCode**)!

In both cases, **$user** is returned correctly.

```
    $user = get_user_by( 'login', $memberCode );

    if($user != false){

        //Get the guid of this user
        $guid = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'guid', true);
```

Any pointers to what the problem could be or how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you trace the SQL queries somehow, and see if it’s going to the database, what SQL it’s running and whether the value is coming back from the database?

Comment: not sure how I can trace the query since this is hosted on a third party, but I can ask.

Comment: You need to start by checking the value of `$user`.  Where/how to trace your problem depends entirely upon whether `$user` is a valid user object (and thus, valid ID) or if it's `false`.  So right now, you don't know if the problem is `get_user_by()` or `get_user_meta()`

Comment: Where/how is `guid` being saved?

Comment: @butlerblog: $user is correct.  In both cases I checked and $user->ID returns the same ID which is correct when I checked in the database

Comment: @JacobPeattie guid is being saved in the User Meta table, an SQL query shows data is correct.

Comment: Does testing with a known user ID for a known "guid" value return a valid result?  i.e. `$guid = get_user_meta( '123', 'guid', true);` when 123 is confirmed as a known user and is known to have a valid meta for "guid"?

Comment: No.  For all known users, the guid returns blank AFTER the upgrade to 6.1.1. (just after the upgrade).  Restoring back 6.0.3 gives you the correct guid.

Comment: :-/ I think you'll have to debug into get_user_meta then. No idea what that could be though. Do other meta values work if you have them, just guid broken?

Comment: Other values do work.  Reverting to v6.0.3 solved the problem for now.  So it's a temporary solution — hope it does not happen in future version!